# Decimal output from Datediff - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, type-conversion, datediff

I expect to get float/decimal outputs from below code. However, all I get is 0's or 1's.

```
CAST((CASE
        WHEN Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date]>Setup.[End] OR Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date]<Setup.[Start] OR Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date] IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date]<=Setup.[Start] AND Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date]<=Setup.[END] THEN ROUND(DATEDIFF(DAY,Setup.[Start],Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date])/365,2)
        WHEN Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date]<=Setup.[Start] AND Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date]>=Setup.[END] THEN 1
        WHEN Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date]<=Setup.[End] AND Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date]<=Setup.[END] THEN ROUND(DATEDIFF(DAY,Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date],Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date])/365,2)
        WHEN Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date]<=Setup.[End] AND Contract_hist.[I1 G Contract End Date]>=Setup.[END] THEN ROUND(DATEDIFF(DAY,Contract_hist.[I1 F Contract Start Date],Setup.[END])/365,2)
        ELSE 'Else'
        END) AS FLOAT) AS ContractDuration
```

Any helping idea is appreciated.

Comment: try to convert before. I mean when selecting values. Not only one time at the end.

Comment: Replace `365` by `365.0` or cast dadediff to float